# GROUP by data by time range in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to `GROUP by` data by time range. The example I have `start_date` and `end_date`, and I want
the separate range between `start_date` and `end_date` on `25` range and get sum `value` from `1` to `25`.

Simple presentation of my table:

```
select * from t1
where time between start_date and end_date
```

table t1 have:

```
time 2019-10-01 value 50
time 2019-10-01 value 50
time 2019-10-02 value 50
time 2019-10-02 value 50
time 2019-10-02 value 50
time 2019-10-02 value 50
time 2019-10-03 value 50
time 2019-10-04 value 50
time 2019-10-05 value 50
time 2019-10-05 value 50
time 2019-10-05 value 50

start_date 2019-10-01
end_date   2019-10-25
```

`generate_series` function to separate on

```
2019-10-01
2019-10-02
2019-10-03
2019-10-04
2019-10-05
2019-10-06 
2019-10-07 
2019-10-07 
2019-10-07 
2019-10-08 
2019-10-09 
2019-10-10 
2019-10-11 
2019-10-12 
2019-10-13 
2019-10-14 
2019-10-15 
2019-10-16 
2019-10-17 
2019-10-18 
2019-10-19 
2019-10-20 
2019-10-21 
2019-10-22 
2019-10-23 
2019-10-24 
2019-10-25
```

and sum by how this 25

for `2019-10-01` to have value `100`
for `2019-10-02` to have value `400`

Comment: Hi, can you also show a few sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Just a second, please.

Comment: Now you can see what is my problem and what I want to do. Does anyone have any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to recommend a lateral join:

```
select d.dt, t.total_value
from generate_series(date '2019-10-01', date '2019-10-25', interval '1' day
                    ) d(dt) left join lateral
      (select coalesce(sum(value), 0) as total_value
       from t
       where t.time >= d.dt and
             t.time < d.dt + interval '1' day
      ) t
      on true;
```

A lateral join can have better performance than overall aggregation, particularly with an index on `(time, value)`.

Comment: I forgot to say, start_date and end_date will be automatically changed from function. Sometimes a will get a range of 3 days with hours. This is the same comment from the answer above
`start_date = 2019-01-01 23:59:59 end_date = 2019-01-05 20:59:59`

Comment: @SInsansun . . . Just adjust the `generate_series()` and comparison for whatever time frame you want.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to generate a list of days, and compute the sum of a column for each:

```
select d.dt, coalesce(sum(value), 0) total_value
from 
    generate_series(date'2019-10-01', date'2019-10-25', interval '1' day) as d(dt)
    left join mytable t 
        on t.time >= d.dt
        and t.time < d.dt + interval '1' day
group by d.dt
order by d.dt
```

On dates for which no record is available in your table, `total_value` will display `0`.

Comment: I forgot to say,  `start_date` and `end_date` will be automatically changed from function. Sometimes a will get a range of 3 days with hours. This is the same comment from the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `start_date` and `end_date` are variables, you might wanna try the following [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). It will group by a sum over `value` by time. In case you want to replace the `null` values with a `0`, try [`coalesce`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html) as pointed out by @GMB in the other answer.

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT generate_series(DATE '2019-10-01', DATE '2019-10-25', '1 day') AS day)
SELECT j.day, coalesce(sum(value), 0) FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN j ON j.day = time
GROUP BY j.day ORDER BY j.day;

          day           | coalesce 
------------------------+----------
 2019-10-01 00:00:00+02 |      100
 2019-10-02 00:00:00+02 |      200
 2019-10-03 00:00:00+02 |       50
 2019-10-04 00:00:00+02 |       50
 2019-10-05 00:00:00+02 |      150
 2019-10-06 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-07 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-08 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-09 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-10 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-11 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-12 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-13 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-14 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-15 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-16 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-17 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-18 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-19 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-20 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-21 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-22 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-23 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-24 00:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-25 00:00:00+02 |        0
(25 rows)
```

**EDIT** (see comments below):

Changing the series with a 12 hours interval between the generated elements.

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT generate_series(DATE '2019-10-01 01:30:00', 
                        DATE '2019-10-03 12:30:00', '12 hours') AS day)
SELECT j.day, coalesce(sum(value),0) FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN j ON j.day = time
GROUP BY j.day ORDER BY j.day;

          day           | coalesce 
------------------------+----------
 2019-10-01 00:00:00+02 |      100
 2019-10-01 12:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-02 00:00:00+02 |      200
 2019-10-02 12:00:00+02 |        0
 2019-10-03 00:00:00+02 |       50
(5 rows)
```

You can change the parameters inside of the `generate_series` function as you wish, e.g. `30 minutes`, `1 hour`, etc.

The same can be done with `TIMESTAMP`, but the dates you'll join with your table need to be identical!

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT generate_series(TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 00:00:00', 
                        TIMESTAMP '2019-10-05 12:30:00', '8 hours') AS day)
SELECT j.day, coalesce(sum(value),0) FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN j ON j.day = time
GROUP BY j.day ORDER BY j.day;

         day         | coalesce 
---------------------+----------
 2019-10-01 00:00:00 |      100
 2019-10-01 08:00:00 |        0
 2019-10-01 16:00:00 |        0
 2019-10-02 00:00:00 |      200
 2019-10-02 08:00:00 |        0
 2019-10-02 16:00:00 |        0
 2019-10-03 00:00:00 |       50
 2019-10-03 08:00:00 |        0
 2019-10-03 16:00:00 |        0
 2019-10-04 00:00:00 |       50
 2019-10-04 08:00:00 |        0
 2019-10-04 16:00:00 |        0
 2019-10-05 00:00:00 |      150
 2019-10-05 08:00:00 |        0
(14 rows)
```

Comment: I forgot to say,  `start_date` and `end_date` will be automatically changed from function. Sometimes a will get a range of 3 days with hours.